# Can one Google Chrome extension have several browser action icons?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've made an extension that adds one icon that shows a popup. But I need to show 2 icons. I've read the https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction but couldn't find a reference to any limitations on this regard. However in the manifest.json, I can only define one popup.

Is there a way for one extension to have several icons on the Chrome toolbar?

Comment: Not to *Well, ackchyually* this, but technically, the answer is **yes**, an extension can have as many browser action **icons** as it wants. It can change the icon at any time using the `chrome.browserAction.setIcon()` method. However, an extension can have only one browser action **button** on the toolbar, so it can only show one icon at a time. (Just in case someone got here looking for how to change the icon.)

Comment: Firefox's extensions are allowed more than one. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386806/multiple-icons-on-pageaction-chrome-extension/74210394#74210394)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. [Each extension can have at most one browser action or page action.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) You could create multiple extensions [that pass messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external).

Comment: but if I create multiple extensions, the user has to install them separately and manually right?

Comment: Yes. If you want multiple browser actions this is the only way to do it though. Some people have the browser action open trigger the popup and have multiple HTML buttons in there.