# Multiple icons on pageAction chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that the manifest file allow only 1 icon, but can I update the icon on different urls?

For example show a red icon in Google, and on youtube it has another icon. Is that possible? Can I update the icon in js, if not in the manifest file?

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction)?

Comment: @Xan couldn;'t find what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ThianKianPhin Did Xan's answer below work for you? If so, it should be marked as correct. IMHO it's the only way, you need to use the setIcon-method; you cannot change the manifest itself, cause that's fixed once the extension is loaded by the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to find in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-setIcon):

> `chrome.pageAction.setIcon(object details, function callback)`
>
> Sets the icon for the page action. The icon can be specified either as the path to an image file or as the pixel data from a canvas element, or as dictionary of either one of those. Either the path or the imageData property must be specified.

You need to pass a Tab ID to it, e.g.

```
chrome.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: id, path: 'icon.png'});
```

For more options, see the above documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given are correct, a Chrome extension is allowed one of either a [PageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/pageAction/) button or a [BrowserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/) button.

But that is not true for Firefox extensions, which allow one [page_ction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/page_action) button (a.k.a. [address bar button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Page_actions)) and one [browser_action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_actionn) button (a.k.a. [toolbar button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Browser_action)).