# Can I implement multiple icons for one Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop an extension that has two icons, and for each icon clicked a new modal / pop-up is showed. Is this somehow possible? In `manifest.json` for example when I add an array of `.png` into `default_icon` a non-image appears in Google Chrome instead of my intended array of `.png`.

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: 10x for help. I've made research for this issue, and you are right @Daniel, it is not possible.

Comment: Firefox's extensions are allowed more than one. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386806/multiple-icons-on-pageaction-chrome-extension/74210394#74210394)